# mysql schema for a user reporting user

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with mysql tables for a user reporting another user.
I have a table named user that has atributes like name,email,password etc, and another table reports that has atributes fk_user(who reports), fk_user(who is reported), description. can a table have two foreign keys like this

Comment: Put the source code please, you should first go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `employee_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `employee_manager` (
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `manager_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`,`manager_id`),
  KEY `fk_manager` (`manager_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_manager_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`employee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_manager_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`employee_id`)
);
```

Or, you could do the whole thing in one with a self-referencing table

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `manager_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
  KEY `manager_id` (`manager_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`employee_id`)
);
```